# Why does every irreducible component have codimension one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm a bit confused on the following lemma.  Here $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is the set of one dimensional subspaces of $V$.  With the choice of a basis for $V$, there is a natural bijection $\mathbb{P}(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{\textrm{Dim }V-1}$ through which you give $\mathbb{P}(V)$ the structure of a variety.  It doesn't depend on which basis you use.

[image]

You can choose the basis for $V$ in such a way that $\mathbb{P}(W)$ is identified with $\{ \overline{(x_1, ... , x_n)} \in \mathbb{P}^{n-1} : x_n = 0\}$, and the complement is the affine open set $U_n$.

So I understand why $X$ must have nonempty intersection with $\mathbb{P}(W)$.  I don't understand how the rest of the lemma follows from the theorems.

Theorem 3.3 and Corollary 3.2 are converses to one another.  Combining them you get the statement: *Let $X$ be an affine irreducible variety, and $Y \subseteq X$ a closed, irreducible subset.  Then $Y$ has codimension $1$ in $X$ if and only if $Y$ is an irreducible component of $\mathcal V(f)$ for some nonzero nonunit $f \in k[X]$.*

I'm confused because I don't see how to reduce the lemma to the affine case.

Comment: If you copy something from a book it is imperative that you give a reference to that book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get back to affine space to apply your lemma, take the cone of everything. Hartshorne page 12, Ex. 2.10. Then you can apply Hartshorne page 8, Ex. 1.8 (which is basically the lemma above).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very general point about how codimension is defined. Given a closed embedding of schemes $i : X \hookrightarrow Y$, we say that the embedding is codimension-$r$ at $p \in X$ if in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{Y,i(p)}$, the ideal cutting out $X$ is generated by a length-$r$ regular sequence. The embedding is codimension-$r$ if it is codimension-$r$ at all $p \in X$. So you just need to check this criterion at every point, and moving to affine patches to check it is perfectly fine.

I would suggest reading Section 8.4 of Ravi Vakil's FOAG for a wonderful treatment of codimension.